# HDMI Termination analysis

Tags: hdmi

Recently came across one ULX FPGA board add-on. HDMI TMDS signals are terminating on this board. I am unable to understand why highlighted resistors are used for. Seems like some sort of voltage divider for only DP lanes of TMDS. Can anyone help me understand?

[image]

Comment: BRD sounds like an abbreviation. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 0):

> *I am unable to understand why highlighted resistors are used*

Those resistors lightly bias the voltages of the data outputs that feed the PMOD connector to mid-rail. They won't significantly attenuate signals coming from the GPDI connector but, given that these signals are capacitively coupled (C1 to C9), a bias network is needed (your highlighted resistors) to restore the signal levels to a suitable mid-point for the device connected to PMOD.